# adding the "/" character in my footer links wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need some help. I am stuck with adding the "/" in the footer links of my wordpress secondary link menu. I want to add "/" between the navigation of my `<div id="footer-right">`. I am using wordpress.

here is my code in footer :

```
<div class="footer">
        <section id="footer">
            <div id="footer-left">
            <ul id="copyright">
                <br>
                <li>Copyright &copy; JCJOHN. </li>
                <li>Designed by: <a href="">JC</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="footer-right">
            <br>
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'secondary')); ?>
            </div>
        </section>

    </div>
```

here is my css :

```
#footer-left {
     float:left;
}
#footer-right {
     float:right;
     margin-right: 18px;
}
#footer-left,#footer-right li {
    clear:both;
}
#footer-right ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 8px 5px;

}
#footer-right li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
}
#footer-right ul.sf-menu li:after {
    content: "/" !important;
    float: right;
}
```

when I added `#footer-right ul.sf-menu li:after` in my css, it also outputting into nothhing. please help.

Comment: I don't think you want to `float: right;`. Instead, I think you want `display: inline-block;`. Are you able to replicate the generated HTML and CSS in a Stack Snippet or Fiddle?

Comment: Incidentally `<br>` is *not* a valid child of the `<ul>` element (it can only contain `<li>` elements as children).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:right` and give some `left/right margin`

**Notes**

- avoid using `!important`
- `ul` can only have `li` has direct descendant, so remove/rearrange the `br` in your `footer-left`

```css
#footer-left {
  float: left;
}
#footer-right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 18px;
}
#footer-left,
#footer-right li {
  clear: both;
}
#footer-right ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 8px 5px;
}
#footer-right li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px;
}
#footer-right ul.sf-menu li:after {
  content: " / ";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: red
  /* demo */
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <section id="footer">
    <div id="footer-left">
      <br>
      <ul id="copyright">
        <li>Copyright &copy; JCJOHN.</li>
        <li>Designed by: <a href="">JC</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-right">
      <br>
      <ul class="sf-menu">
        <li>Copyright &copy; JCJOHN.</li>
        <li>Designed by: <a href="">JC</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: hi sir.. can i ask a little bit again ? how can i remove the last "/" for example Home / About us / Contact Us "/" <-- how can i remove the last sir ?

Comment: Add something like this `#footer-right ul.sf-menu li:last-of-type:after { content: " ";}`